# What type of regression to use with negative values?

Tags: r, regression

If possible, please explain things like I'm 5.  I know very little about this subject, but would like to learn more.

I have a data frame (in R) containing `player_id`, `points`, `away`, `opponent_fact_1`, `opponent_fact_2`.  `points` can be negative.  `away` lets us know if the game was at home or away (0 or 1).  `opponent_fact_1` and `opponent_fact_2` gives us a stat about the opponent.  `opponent_fact_1` is on a scale of about 0.0-5.5.  `opponent_fact_2` is on a scale of about 70.0-95.0.  The issue with the two facts is that there are fewer opponents as you reach the upper and lower bounds, so fewer data points exist at those levels.

How can I determine how much of an influence `away`, `opponent_fact_1`, and `opponent_fact_2` has on a player's `points`?

I asked someone online how to do this and he said use poisson regression, but didn't go into detail.  Why would regression be helpful here?  What is it?  And I read that you can't use poisson regression with negative values?  Also, how do I deal with the fewer data points around the upper and lower bounds?

I'm using R, so any examples in R would be awesome.  Explaining the output would be even better.

I hope this isn't asking for too much.

**EDIT: Added sample data**

```
  player_id opponent_team_id away  points opponent_fact_1 opponent_fact_2 
1       695               22    0     0.0        2.888889           81.58 
2       695               30    1     1.2        2.750000           81.58 
3       695                4    1     3.0        3.714286           69.57 
4       695               20    0    -3.0        3.000000           84.09 
5       695               14    0     0.0        2.444444           72.97
```

Comment: What exactly does `points` measure and what relationship does it have (if any) to a player's "score"?  (Or is the score a separate variable altogether?)  Note, too, that your ability to assess "influence" in any material or causal sense depends on how you collected these data: if they are just records of the outcomes of contests, then most likely you cannot estimate influence at all, but you might be able to identify some *quantitative relationships* among the variables.

Comment: It might help to post the first few lines of your data, in `R` you can do this with `head`.

Comment: `points` is a combination of the player's assists, goals, penalties (negative), etc...  where each attribute has a multiplier.  I should reword that to be `points` and not `score`.  Good catch.

Comment: opponent facts are things like the opponent's "average points allowed per game"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular linear regression (e.g. the `lm` or `glm` functions in R) handles negative values just fine.

One model you could try would be:

```
model1 <- lm(points ~ away + opponent_fact_1 + opponent_fact_2, data=my_data_frame)
summary(model1)
```

If you've got a lot of data (and several rows per player and per opponent), you could also try this model:

```
model2 <- lm(points ~ away + factor(player_id) + factor(opponent_team_id), data=my_data_frame)
summary(model2)
```

This will give you a model that includes a coefficient for each player, and for each opponent_team_id.  These coefficients will represent the average points expected for a player, as well as the average points expected against a given opponent.

Have you every run a regression model before?  What's the goal of this analysis?

Comment: Thanks, I have never run a regression model before.  The goal is to see what opponent_facts have the biggest influence on a player's points.  And ideally, how much should I expect a player's points to increase or decrease.

I'm looking at the "Estimate" column of the summary.  It tells me that a certain player_id has an Estimate of -2.7648, but I see their mean points is 2.975.  Is the Estimate column the one you were talking about where I can see the "average points expected for a player" or the "average points expected against a given opponent".  That would be really cool to know.

Comment: @Bradford: Yes it is, but that "estimate" is for that player, against the AVERAGE opponent.  So in your example, the regression model thinks that that player has an estimated mean points of -2.7648, but they played against easier than average opponents, which is the reason their actually average points is 2.975.  In other words, the regression model corrects for the fact that each player has played a different set of opponents, and some of those opponents might have been easier (or harder) than average.